# Spring Boot and FlywayTest cause JPA Camel routes to throw exceptions during database reset

Tags: jpa, testing, apache-camel, spring-boot, flyway

I have a Spring Boot application that contains a Camel route with a JPA consumer.

When running a test that uses the @FlyTest annotation the database is reset as expected prior to the test but while this is happening the Camel JPA consumer tries to execute an SQL select against the database.

How do I disable the route while FlywayTest is resetting the database?

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I worked around the problem by setting consumer.initialDelay=5000 which was sufficient to allow Flyway to reset the DB.

Answer (score 0):

A more robust approach to solving this was to suspend the Camel routes in my tests by using:

```
@Autowired
CamelContext camelContext;

@Before
public void init() throws Exception {
    camelContext.suspend();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Camel 2.15 (current master branch) I recently delayed CamelContext startup. The routes should not be started so early then. Therefore the routes should not consume from JPA too early as well.

If you still experience this issue - feel free to drop me a line. I will fix it.

Comment: Is there a property that can be used to set the delay time?

Answer (score 0):

I configured my application to start all Camel routes after the Flyway migration is complete. This proved very important on slow machines or large databases where the migration could be very slow.

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new SpringApplication((Object[])args).run();
    }

    @Bean 
    @DependsOn({"flyway","dataSource"})
    CamelContext camelContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext,
                              CamelConfigurationProperties configurationProperties) {
        CamelContext camelContext = new SpringCamelContext(applicationContext);
        SpringCamelContext.setNoStart(true);

        if (!configurationProperties.isJmxEnabled()) {
            camelContext.disableJMX();
        }

        if (configurationProperties.getName() != null) {
            ((SpringCamelContext) camelContext).setName(configurationProperties.getName());
        }

        camelContext.setAutoStartup(false);

        return camelContext;
    }

    @Bean 
    FlywayCallback flywayCallback(Flyway flyway, final CamelContext camelContext) {
        FlywayCallback callback = new FlywayCallback() {

            @Override
            public void beforeClean(Connection connection) {}
            @Override
            public void afterClean(Connection connection) {}
            @Override
            public void beforeMigrate(Connection connection) {}
            @Override
            public void afterMigrate(Connection connection) {
                try {
                    camelContext.startAllRoutes();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    throw new RuntimeException("Camel startup failed", e);
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void beforeEachMigrate(Connection connection,
                    MigrationInfo info) {}
            @Override
            public void afterEachMigrate(Connection connection,
                    MigrationInfo info) {}
            @Override
            public void beforeValidate(Connection connection) {}
            @Override
            public void afterValidate(Connection connection) {}
            @Override
            public void beforeBaseline(Connection connection) {}
            @Override
            public void afterBaseline(Connection connection) {}
            @Override
            public void beforeInit(Connection connection) {}
            @Override
            public void afterInit(Connection connection) {}
            @Override
            public void beforeRepair(Connection connection) {}
            @Override
            public void afterRepair(Connection connection) {}
            @Override
            public void beforeInfo(Connection connection) {}
            @Override
            public void afterInfo(Connection connection) {}
        };
        flyway.setCallbacks(callback);
        return callback;
    }

}
```